# how can we extract massively huge data from zipped json file on s3 bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, bucket

how can we extract massively huge data from zipped json file on s3 bucket?
Given a zipped json file in s3 bucket.
need to extract the file and unzip it

Comment: What problem are you facing now?

Answer (score 2):

As the file(s) is (are) on S3, your only option is to copy the file(s) to a filesystem, then unzip the file(s).

S3 is an object store, and it's not possible to directly unzip files directly in that location.